# Intuitive argument for Polynomial division in $\mathbb C[t,x]$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let $h(t,x)$  and $f ( t, x)$  be nonzero elements of $\mathbb C[t,x]$. Suppose that $h$ is not divisible by any polynomial of the form $t-\alpha$. If $h$ divides $f$ in $\mathcal F[x]$, then $h$ divides $f$ in $\mathbb C[t,x]$.
This proposition can be found in the book "Algebra" by Artin.

The proof seemed to be easy but when I tried to embed the intuition into logic, I got stuck.

Proof:

we have, $f  =  h q$ ,  where $q \in \mathcal F[x]$, it is a polynomial in $x$ whose coefficients are rational functions in $t$. We multiply both  sides of the equation  $f  =  h q$  by a  monic polynomial  in $t$ to clear 
denominators in these coefficients. This gives us an equation of the form
$u ( t) f ( t, x)  = h (t, x) q_1(t, x )$.

Let $\alpha $ be a root of $u(t)$, then $t-\alpha$ divedes RHS as well, $t — \alpha$ does not divide $h$,  so $h(\alpha,x)$  is not zero. 
Since the polynomial ring $\mathbb C[x]$ is an integral domain, $q_1 (\alpha, x)  = 0$, and the lemma shows that $t-\alpha$ divides $q_1(t, x)$. We cancel $t-\alpha$ from $u$ and $q_1$.

Problem: (All the implications below are mine, so can thus be wrong)

We have $q \in \mathcal F[x]$ where $\mathcal F = \mathbb C (t)=$ a rational field of $\mathbb C [t]$.

So, $q=\frac{a_n(t)}{b_n(t)}x^n+\frac{a_{n-1}(t)}{b_{n-1}(t)}x^{n-1}+\frac{a_{1}(t)}{b_{1}(t)}x+\frac{a_{0}(t)}{b_{0}(t)}$

where $ q_1 \in \mathbb{C}[t,x]$. Let $q_1=u(t)*q=c_{n}(t)x^n+c_{n-1}(t)x^{n-1}+\cdots+c_{1}(t)x+c_{0}(t)$, where, $u(t)=lcm(b_{n}(t),b_{n-1}(t),\cdots, b_{0}(t))$ and $c_j(t)=\frac{u(t)}{b_j(t)}a_{j}(t)$.

$(t-\alpha)|q_1 \Rightarrow (t-\alpha)| c_{j}(t) \; \forall \; j={1,\cdots,n} $. let $(t-\alpha)$ has multiplicity $k$ in $u(t)$ which is due to some $b_{p}(t)$. Now, $c_{p}(t)$ will not have any power of $(t-\alpha)$ which would mean $(t-\alpha)$ does not divide $c_j(t) \; \forall j$, which is a contradiction to what I have assumed initially. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What you write is correct, but what is the question/problem?

Comment: $q_1(\alpha , x)=0 \Rightarrow (t-\alpha)$ is a factor of $q_1$ but what I wrote in Problem section, suggests that there will be term in $q_1$ which doesn't get divided by $(t-\alpha)$ and hence, $q_1(\alpha , x) \neq 0$.

Comment: Yes, and so what's the problem? We get a contradiction and celebrate.

Comment: In the proof section, it is proven that $q_1(\alpha ,x)=0$ but in the problem section, I am concluding that $q_1(\alpha,x) \neq 0$. So, there must be some fallacy or gaps in my argument. I just want to know, where the fallacy is?

Comment: You really should clear up the meaning of your notation: your $\mathcal F$ is what the rest of the world would write as $\mathbf C(t)$. Anyway, this is Gauss' lemma. Find a proof of it first in $\mathbf Z[x]$ before trying to understand it in $\mathbf C[t,x] = \mathbf C[t][x]$. Ultimately it is about polynomials in $x$ with coefficients in a PID, but learn the most basic case like $\mathbf Z$ first.

Comment: No fallacy, you assumed that $u$ is non-constant (to get $\alpha$) and arrived to a contradiction.

Comment: Sorry, I did not proceed further to infer that $u(t)$, thus, is constant and $h$  divides $f$ in $\mathbb C[t,x]$